# URL for bootstrap tab, doesn't lead to the correct tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've seen a few of related questions arround here, but I couldn't find a solution for me so far.

Here's the thing: I have a `tab` section with the same structure as [this](https://codepen.io/rnr/pen/dMNZmx/) and it's working just fine. But if I create an URL to, let's say, the second tab, like this `www.example.com/path/to#tab2` it takes me to the default tab, tab1.

In my research, I read that something this could be a solution:

```
$(function(){
  var hash = window.location.hash;
  hash && $('ul.nav a[href="' + hash + '"]').tab('show');

  $('.nav-tabs a').click(function (e) {
    $(this).tab('show');
    var scrollmem = $('body').scrollTop();
    window.location.hash = this.hash;
    $('html,body').scrollTop(scrollmem);
  });
});
```

After that, if I go to `www.example.com/path/to` and navigate the tabs, they are working as before, however, if I go directly to this url `www.example.com/path/to#tab2`, I get this error in the console:

`Uncaught TypeError: $(...).tab is not a function`

And as far as I know, that's a problem with Jquery loading, which makes no sense to me because my `.js` file already has jquery functions and they are working.

Jquery version: 1.12.4;

Bootstrap version: 3.3.5;

Comment: [Try this](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OvRJvp) (forked from that Pen you shared).

Comment: @SallyCJ Good try, but it goes to the default tab when acessing other tabs URL, or, in other words, when you refresh the page

Comment: Are you sure? I've actually changed it (a few times) since I posted my comment. Try to create a simple HTML template (yet a valid one) and put all the HTML and JS script into that file. Then test it from your local dev site or even a live site if you want.

Comment: @SallyCJ I'm sorry, I meant to say it goes to the default tab on my dev site even tho it works fine on your pen

Comment: Actually, the script does work well (at least on Edge). [Download this HTML file](https://pastebin.com/bzd9DfDB) and just open it from your browser, with or without accessing it from a `http://` URL (i.e. with or without uploading it to your server/site). (The HTML is different from the one I used on my [Pen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OvRJvp).)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually found the answer myself, this is what I did:

```
var hash = document.location.hash;
var prefix = '/';

if (hash) {
  $('.nav-tabs a[href="' + hash.replace(prefix, '') + '"]').tab('show');
}
```

I was close to make it work, just wasn't using the correct prefix before.